# Calling a method from a binding is giving a "no match for call" error

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am trying to make a wrapper for a Gtk click signal to hook into my event system. The Gtk way to handle click events would be like this:

```cpp
auto button = new Gtk::Button();
button->signal_clicked().connect(...);
```

So, to add it to my system I created a function called `fromSignal` which takes two inputs and I will bind them together. The problem that I am running into is on the `callback();` line.

```
error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (Gtk::Button::*(Gtk::Widget*))()>) ()'
[build]    18 |   callback();
[build]       |   ~~~~~~~~^~
```

Here is the wrapper:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void _signalCallback(_Bind<Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (T::*(Widget*))()> callback) {
  callback();
  printf("callback\n");
}

template <typename T>
void fromSignal(Gtk::Widget* widget, Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (T::*f)()) {
  auto b = std::bind(f, widget);
  _signalCallback<T>(b);
}


void main() {
  auto button = new Gtk::Button();
  fromSignal<Gtk::Button>(button, &Gtk::Button::signal_clicked);
}
```

I tried changing the definition of `_signalCallabck` which then gives me the following error:

```cpp
void _signalCallback(function<Glib::SignalProxy<void()>()> callback);

// The error message:
error: could not convert 'b' from 'std::_Bind<Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (Gtk::Button::*(Gtk::Widget*))()>' to 'std::function<Glib::SignalProxy<void()>()>'
[build]    26 |   _signalCallback<T>(b);
[build]       |                      ^
[build]       |                      |
[build]       |                      std::_Bind<Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (Gtk::Button::*(Gtk::Widget*))()>
```

What is the correct way to do this? Am I overly complicating this?

Comment: Remember that all symbols beginning with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter, like for example `_Bind`, is a symbol reserved by the compiler and standard library. If you need to use such symbols then I would argue that it's a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that it looked like an incorrect way to do it. Everywhere else uses the `function` type as a parameter like my last block of code, but I couldn't get that working.

Comment: My recommendation is that you look at how the standard library itself does when it comes to callable objects: Plain template argument. As in `template<typename F> void _signalCallback(F callback) { /* ... */ }`. Similar change to `fromSignal`. Couple that with lambdas.

Comment: The gist of your error messages is that `bind(f, widget)` (is that `std:bind`?) cannot be invoked with no arguments. Could you provide an explanation of why it should work that way? Maybe write out what the expression would be without the `bind`?

Comment: *"Am I overly complicating this?"* -- Probably, but I don't know anything about your event system, so I cannot be sure.

Comment: @JaMiT not sure what you mean by "Write it out", but this is the expression without the bind `button->signal_clicked();`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes, that is what I meant. Although now I see that it's the expression from inside `fromSignal` that would be illuminating, `widget->signal_clicked()`. Clicked signal on an arbitrary widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates make a mess of error messages. I propose three simplifications to your example code.

First, since `_signalCallback` will just invoke its parameter, it's easy to inline. So `_signalCallback<T>(b)` becomes `b()`. One template eliminated. Second, we can replace the `fromSignal` function template with a function for the specified template argument, `Gtk::Button`. The other template eliminated. However, there is one more template messing with the error message, namely `std::bind`.

The third simplification is to drop `std::bind` and write out the equivalent expression. (I'll also throw in an alias to make the signature easier to read.

```cpp
using RetType = Glib::SignalProxy<void()>;

void fromSignal(Gtk::Widget* widget, RetType (Gtk::Button::*f)()) {
  (widget->*f)();
}
```

Compiling this gives a more informative error message:

> error: pointer to member type `RetType (Gtk::Button::)()` {aka 'Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (Gtk::Button::)()'} incompatible with object type `Gtk::Widget`

The compiler is complaining because you cannot take an arbitrary `Widget` and expect it to have a member from `Button`. Base classes cannot be used to invoke a method of a derived class. You need a derived class pointer to invoke a member function of the derived class.

Change the type of the first parameter from `Gtk::Widget*` to `T*` so that it corresponds to the type of the second parameter.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fromSignal(T* widget, Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (T::*f)()) {
  auto b = std::bind(f, widget);
  _signalCallback<T>(b);
}
```

A lambda might make the code easier to read.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fromSignal(T* widget, Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (T::*f)()) {
  _signalCallback<T>([widget, f]() { return (widget->*f)(); });
}
```

If you don't like the syntax to invoke a pointer-to-member (which some people find clunky):

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fromSignal(T* widget, Glib::SignalProxy<void()> (T::*f)()) {
  _signalCallback<T>([widget, f]() { return std::invoke(f, widget); });
}
```